# How to find child of a element in ios?

Tags: ios, testing, automation, appium

I can not get child element.

I can see the childNameLabel element under childNameTV element with appium inspector

Example, I try find text of first child element;

```
List<WebElement> webElements = driver.findElements(By.id("childNameTV"));
webElements.get(0).findElement(By.id("childNameLabel")).getText();
```

[image]

**Then i get this error;**

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be
>   located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The
>   server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or
>   timeout: 7.45 seconds For documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13
>   -0700' System info: host: 'cihangir-macbook.local', ip: '10.125.0.57', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.3',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_131' Driver info:
>   com.xamarin.testcloud.appium.EnhancedIOSDriver Capabilities
>   [{app=/Users/cihangirtuna/mobile_app_automation_appium/app/iOS/morhipo.app, networkConnectionEnabled=false, databaseEnabled=false,
>   deviceName=iPhone 6s Plus, xcodeSigningId=iPhone Developer,
>   platform=MAC, waitForQuiescence=false, platformVersion=11.2,
>   webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false,
>   automationName=XCUITest, browserName=, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=iOS,
>   udid=303257C6-5EE7-410F-87E2-466E3716265C, autoAcceptAlerts=true}]
>   Session ID: b522404b-4e02-4d4b-a0c9-2b5ffa1b6d51
>
> ---*Element info: {Using=id, value=childNameLabel}*   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:43)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>     at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileElement.execute(DefaultGenericMobileElement.java:37)
>     at io.appium.java_client.MobileElement.execute(MobileElement.java:1)
>     at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement.execute(IOSElement.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElement(RemoteWebElement.java:177)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElementById(RemoteWebElement.java:210)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileElement.findElementById(DefaultGenericMobileElement.java:53)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.MobileElement.findElementById(MobileElement.java:1)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement.findElementById(IOSElement.java:1)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElement(RemoteWebElement.java:173)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileElement.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileElement.java:45)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.MobileElement.findElement(MobileElement.java:1)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement.findElement(IOSElement.java:1)
>     at pages.NewSeasonPage.tabSeasonSubCategory(NewSeasonPage.java:43)
>     at tests.SortTest.testSortPageOpenWithoutLogin(SortTest.java:31)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
>     at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:47)  at
>   org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:18)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"childNameLabel" is an attribute labeled "name," not an ID.

I suspect the following will work for you:

```
webElements.get(0).findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name=\"childNameLabel\"]")).getText();
```